# How to fix the problem of overriding numerics by windows.h macros?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, c++17

```
    if (timeoutMs >= std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
        intTimeoutMs = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

In this code section, there is an override problem, I use define NOMINMAX, but it does not help to deal with it. I get the following error

error: C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected

I used the compilers for MVSC2017, 2019. I used define NO_MIN_MAX and NOMINMAX.

Also took the code in additional brackets

```
if (timeoutMs >= (std::numeric_limits<int>::max()))
        intTimeoutMs = (std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
```

Comment: Did you have the `#define NOMINMAX` **before** your `#include <Windows.h>`? It has to be so placed.

Comment: @AdrianMole In the header I'm working with, windows.h is not included, it's somewhere in the project. The project is not mine, I'm just trying to build it, but there are some problems with it

Answer (score 0):

As usual, when I wrote a question, I found the answer.
We can radically disable these macros, but we need to remember that we need to be sure that we will not need them

*#undef min
#undef max*

Or use the code from chromium
[Source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/lkgr/src/base/win32-headers.h)

Answer (score 0):

If a macro name is followed by `(`, it is interpreted as a function-like macro. You can stop a function-like macro from expanding by enclosing the macro name in parentheses: `(max)()`.

Comment: The name doesn't have to be followed **immediately** by `(`; there can be intervening whitespace.

Comment: @PeteBecker An unfortunate wording.